# INTERSECT not acting as I expect

Tags: sql, h2

I'm not sure if this is a symptom of my relative inexperience with SQL, or with h2. I have a view, called `VIEW_TRANSACTION_LEGS_DATA`, which I need to search in various ways. So, for example, I have:

```
SELECT HEAD_ID FROM VIEW_TRANSACTION_LEGS_DATA WHERE AMOUNT > 1000
```

and I also have:

```
SELECT * FROM  
(SELECT HEAD_ID FROM VIEW_TRANSACTION_LEGS_DATA WHERE AMOUNT > 1000)  
INTERSECT  
(SELECT HEAD_ID FROM VIEW_TRANSACTION_LEGS_DATA WHERE AMOUNT < 2000)
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working as I expect! There should only be 3 rows returned, whereas I am getting 57 returned.

(Note that the above is a simplified version of what my code actually says; please don't suggest to me to combine the INTERSECTed lines using a BETWEEN since this will not work with the rest of the code.)

I'm sure my problem is a typical SQL newbie type problem, but I simply can't see it!  Can some kind person please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Some example data would help.  Which value gets returned when it should not be?  Consider linking a [SQLFiddle.com example](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Is the problem reproductible with this 'simplified version' or only with your full version? Can you give us simple example with table definition and sample data that *you* confirmed reproduces the problem?

Comment: My bad.  In putting together the example (thanks for the link to SQLFiddle, what an interesting site!) I discovered my error.  If I include AMOUNT in the column list after each SELECT, then it produces the correct result.  Newbie alert...  Many thanks for the help :)